# How long can I extend a hotel stay?

Tags: usa, hotels

I have a guest that wants to keep extending his stay, What are the guidelines for extending a stay in a hotel in Michigan?

Comment: You probably need to ask your lawyer this question.  It's possible that the guest might at some point be considered a tenant, at which point making them leave could require a complicated eviction proceeding.  I would not want to rely on random Internet strangers for something that important to my business.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it probably belongs on the Law stackexchange because it's asking about hotel / tenant issues.